# Retrieve only a part of a string in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a path string something like `'/foo/bar1/bar2/test.txt'`. I want to retrieve just `'/foo/bar1/'` from the string and want to ignore the rest. I tried doing that with `\/([\w\s]+)\/|,(?!\w)+?` but that didn't help.

Can someone help me with this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: What is special with `/foo/bar1/`? For regex, there must be a strict indicator for selecting the right part. Or for **eumiro**'s answer, change in the number of `/` or changing the string might resolve a wrong answer..

What do you really try to do here?...

Answer (score 2):

```
s = '/foo/bar1/bar2/test.txt'

'/'.join(s.split('/')[:3])

# returns '/foo/bar1'
```

Change that `3` to the appropriate number. For further path manipulation have a look at [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) methods.

Comment: thanks eumiro :) ... regex is not always the best solution i guess

Comment: In general, when working with file paths you nearly always want to use either plain string methods (like `split`) or the `os.path` methods, which are robust across operating systems and file path conventions.